# React Fullpage: How to scroll a portion of a section without scrolling the whole section

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events, scroll, fullpage.js

I have a webpage built with React Fullpage where there's a nested scroll box in the first section. I want to be able to scroll within that scrollbox without causing the whole section to scroll away to the next section. I have tried to prevent scroll event bubbling but it doesn't work. Can I get any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using the option `normalScrollElements` for it?
You can read more about it on the [the fullpage.js documentation](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js)